# UI test automation beyond your own app?

Tags: ios, automated-tests, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

Is there some framework which allows to control whole Simulator (to be able to test not only inside your own app, but other apps too)?

I read about:

- [UIAutomation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/UIAutomationRef/_index.html)
- [Test studio for iOS](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/ios-testing.aspx)
- [MonkeyTalk](http://www.gorillalogic.com/testing-tools/monkeytalk/documentation)
- [UISpec](http://code.google.com/p/uispec/)

However, per my understanding, all of them allow to test only within your own application.

I understand that my requirement is very unusual (taking into account that iOS has very limited multitasking). However, I want to write some tests, which will drive Simulator through multiple applications and test that everything works fine.

One additional note. When I said "control Simulator" I meant ability to send some clicks/type something and check controls state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eggplant might be the sort of thing you're after:

https://www.testplant.com/products/eggplant/mobile/

I've never used it, but I've seen it demonstrated. It works by *looking* at the screen, so it can then click areas that you've designated, see whether the result looks the way you've said it should, and so on.

Comment: That's interesting. I will take a look at it.